# Why do I need a <br> in a ul list

Tags: html

I'm just doing basic html but to make sure each item in the list appear on separate line, I need to put a br at the end of each li option.

```
<ul>
    <li>Item One</li><br/>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
</ul>
```

If i don't add the br, then Item two will overlay on Item one.  I've checked the css and there's no entries for li or ul.  Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Looks fine to me: https://codepen.io/lxe/pen/MoLRNP

Comment: You must have some CSS that are causing the `li` to be displayed `inline`, because they are `block` by default which means you would not need a break.

Comment: I don't think `<br />`s are valid children of `<ul>`s. It must be the CSS. How did you verify that there are no CSS rules affecting lists? Did you right-click -> inspect element?

Comment: I looked for any css in the css file that to me looked like it would affect lists.  as for the second question, no, which browser is that in.  Am Using Chrome.

Comment: you can do this in basically every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Set li to:

```
li {

    display: block;

   }
```

Comment: Granted this is like the most basic HTML question ever, but yeah, something is causing your li to not work correctly.

Comment: Put css !important after display:block if you want it to override any other display style for li.

Comment: @Amit  - [using !important does not fix bad code](https://memeexplorer.com/cache/846.jpg). You should look into [**CSS Specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you **don't** need a `<br />` inside your `<ul>`. Using one would result in **invalid markup**. According to the [**official standards on `<ul>`**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), the **only** valid children of `<ul>` are `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>`.

Although there may be no CSS rules targetting `<li>` or `<ul>` elements, your problem **definitely** lies in your CSS. By **default**, `<li>` elements have a `display` attribute with a value of `block`, which would cause them to display below one another.

You probably have some CSS somewhere that is overriding this behaviour, and likely setting it to `display: inline`.

You can override this by manually specifying that the target elements should be block-level:

```
li {
  display: block;
}
```

Keep in mind that as you've not noticed any rules targetting `<li>` elements directly, you may need have another element targetting the `<li>` with [**higher specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). You **can** override this by appending `!important`, but **["*`!important` does not fix your bad CSS*"](https://memeexplorer.com/cache/846.jpg)**. Instead, you should use the **[F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx)** to identify the culprit, and apply **higher specificity**.